# Purpose of OnModelCreating - EF Core Database first Approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I am studying EF Core with database first. There is no issue to get entities and DbContext after reverse-engineering. But I couldn't understand the role(or purpose) OnModelCreating Method in DbContext(database first approach).
Here is code snippet.

```
public partial class VitiLevuContext : DbContext
{ 
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Invoice");
            entity.Property(e => e.DueAmount)
            .IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.PaidAmount).HasColumnType("money");
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Order)
                .WithMany(p => p.Invoices)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.OrderId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__Invoice__OrderId__44FF419A");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Order");
        });
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

Database has a relation and "NOT NULL Contraints".

1. ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Invoice] ADD  FOREIGN KEY ([OrderId]) REFERENCES [dbo].Order     ON DELETE CASCADE.
2. ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Invoice] ADD [DueAmount] int NOT NULL

The OnModelCreating method represents well. I created very simple Rest API project and tested add/delete for Order/Invoice.
"NOT NULL Constraints" and "Cascade deleting" may be verified on database not EF model side.
(In case of creating an invoice instance with null DueAmount, I expected exceptions before submitting to SQL)

My question is very simple.
Can I delete "OnModelCreating" method if don't consider migration?
(I thought the OnModelCreating method is only for migration purpose.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the Entity framework model naming convention and your model directly reflects your database table name, column names and so on, you don't need the OnMOdelCreating method. This is because the entity framework will generate the binding behind the scene.

But, if you want customization, for example, your model field name does not match your database table column name, you configure that on the OnModelCreating method. Another way of using this configuration is called **fluent API**.

This doesn't mean you have to use the OnModelCreating method. There are other options for customization. Which is DataAnotation.

For example:

If you have a model named **User**...

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

on your DbContext, you set the following

```
public AppDbContext : DbContext
{
   public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) {}

   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

So, by [convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in), the Entity framework expects

1. A table named **Users**, because of the name you used on the DbSet property for the User model.
2. It uses **Id** as the primary key.. because the model property name Id

Entity framework will set this all up for you.

When we come to the custom configuration, let's say your model property name *Password* is not the same as the Users table column name *Pwd*. You have to tell the entity framework in one of the following ways.

1. using the OnModelCreating method (fluent API)

   ```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuild)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity => {
             entity.Property(p => p.Password)
                   .HasColumnName("Pwd");
        })  
    }
   ```
2. The other way is Data annotation

   ```
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Column("Pwd")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
   ```

Comment: it is what I want to know.  "If you follow the Entity framework model naming convention and your model directly reflects your database table name, column names and so on, you don't need the OnMOdelCreating method. This is because the entity framework will generate the code behind the scene."